# jquery communication with arcgis services

Tags: javascript, api, jquery

I am working with the ArcGIS JavaScript API for my application.  My app users are stored in a table published in a map service. Whenever a user wants to connect to the app, he needs to provide a username and password. How can I retrieve data from my table and compare them to those entered by the user? I've found somewhere that I need to use JQuery but i don't know how. If you could help, thanks in advance:)

Comment: are you using arcgis server?

Comment: yeah ,i'am using arcgis server 10.0

Comment: Why don't you set up user names and passwords through arcgis server for authentication/authorization. Then you won't need any jQuery..

Comment: Are you storing passwords as something other than a Salted Hash? Are you storing the username and password in plain text in this table?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a query task from the javascript api to query the map service to get the information so you can then compare the usernames and password and you will not have to use jQuery.  There are some security implication associated with this of course.

Comment: thank you for responding, i want just to know what are these security implications and how to manage security of the whole application.i know that i can secure my data by  working with secure services, but how can i secure and restrict access to the whole application ( with user privileges etc) ; i am a beginner in programming and need some help :)

Comment: @sarah according to the question please go through following link contains how to implement security to AGS (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Walk_through_Implementing_security_with_users_and_roles_in_SQL_Server/0093000000pr000000/) Let us know if you  have any question..thanks